# Controlling the frequency of dotting in a plot

Tags: plotting

It is possible to make a dotted `ListPlot`.  For example:

```
x = Range[0, 1, 0.0001];
y = Sin[x];
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dotted]
```

[image: Dotted]

Is it possible to modify the frequency (i.e., spacing) of dotting?

Comment: See `AbsoluteDashing`

Comment: Since `Dotted` is the same as `Dashing[{0, Small}]`, you could replace `Small` with `Medium` or `Large`...

Comment: Related: "[Plotting with dotted lines, not dashed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Ay4Gdf7ppjg/mjcpRHWKXu4J)" (MathGroups).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is indeed. As the documentation states, `Dotted` is equivalent to `Dashing[{0, Small}]`:

So for example

```
x = Range[0, 1, 0.0001];
y = Sin[x];
Table[ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Dashing[{0, d}]], {d, 0.01, 0.1, 0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

```
x = Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.01];
y = Sin[x];
Framed@
  ListPlot[(Transpose[{x, y + #}]) & /@ #, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    Joined -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> (AbsoluteDashing[{#, 15 - #}] & /@ #), 
    Axes -> {False, True}] &@{3, 8, 12}
```

[image]